# Newly built Gigabyte B650 Airbus Elite AX doesn’t recognize GPU

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have just built a new system with the following components:

- Gigabyte B650 Altus Elite AX mainboard, and
- 7800x3d processor,
- Be Quiet Dark Pro 4 Cooler,
- Be Quiet Straight Power 12 850w PSU,
- Radeon 7 7800XT GPU and
- 32GB of RAM.

After switching on, doing BIOS upgrades and everything else associated with setting up my GPU isn’t recognized and has 2 red LED on.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just a guess: forgot to connect the PCIe power cable(s) to the GPU?

Comment: `has 2 red LED on` -> Read The Fine Manual?